# how to replace when found funny character

Tags: java

I need replace `...` when found `â€¦`, replace `-` when found `â€“`, replace `'` when found `â€™`, replace `"` when found `â€œ`, replace `/â€[[:cntrl:]]/` when found `/â€[[:cntrl:]]/`.

If using for loop, it will be one by one checking. How to make when it have contain `â€¦`, direct replace `...`?

I have tried using `getBytes(StandardCharsets.ISO_8859_1)`, but it have error.

Below is my code:

```
public void processRawNews(String rootPath,String filename) throws Exception {

    try {
        //@debug 
        out.println("debug 1= ");
        JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(newsMLObj.class);
        out.println("debug 2= " + jaxbContext);
        SAXParserFactory spf = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
        out.println("debug 3= " + spf);
        XMLReader xr = spf.newSAXParser().getXMLReader();

        // to bypass XML DocType and Entity as Jap did not provide proper XML
        xr.setFeature("http://xml.org/sax/features/validation", false);
        xr.setFeature("http://apache.org/xml/features/nonvalidating/load-dtd-grammar", false);
        xr.setFeature("http://apache.org/xml/features/nonvalidating/load-external-dtd", false);
        xr.setFeature("http://xml.org/sax/features/external-general-entities", false);
        xr.setFeature("http://xml.org/sax/features/external-parameter-entities", false);
        xr.setFeature("http://xml.org/sax/features/use-entity-resolver2", false);
        out.println("debug 4= " + xr);
        // remove UTF-8-Bom
        Path path = Paths.get(rootPath + filename);
        out.println("debug 5= " + path);
        byte[] xmlcontent = Files.readAllBytes(path);
        String s = new String(xmlcontent, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
        s = s.replaceFirst("^\uFEFF", "");
        byte[] content2 = s.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);

        if (content2.length != xmlcontent.length) {
            Files.write(path, content2);
        }
    } catch (JAXBException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        out.println(e.getMessage() + " at processRawNews");
        StackTraceElement[] st = e.getStackTrace();
        for (int i = 0 ; i < st.length ; i ++){
            out.println(st[i].toString());
        }
    }
```

Comment: Maybe you should figure out why you have funny characters. Are you sure UTF-8 is the correct encoding?

Comment: yes, it is UTF-8